# Elm forms onInput usage with numbers

Tags: web, functional-programming, elm

onInput works fine when my model is of type `String`. However if I want the user to enter an `Int` onInput gives me the following error:

```
 Function `onInput` is expecting the argument to be:
      String -> msg
  But it is:
      Int -> Msg
```

This is my code below

```
view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ input [type_ "text", placeholder "Id", onInput Msgs.NewPlayerId] []
        , input [type_ "text", placeholder "Name", onInput Msgs.NewPlayerName ] []
        , input [type_ "number", placeholder "Level", onInput Msgs.NewPlayerLevel ] []
        , button [ onClick Msgs.Submit ] [ text "submit" ]
        ]
```

Is there a built in variation of onInput that accepts Ints or Floats?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you redefine `Msgs.NewPlayerLevel` to accept a `Result String Int` to account for the fact that a player could type in something non-numeric, you could do this:

```elm
type Msg
    = ...
    | NewPlayerLevel (Result String Int)
```

and your `onInput` call would be:

```elm
onInput (NewPlayerLevel << String.toInt)
```

The same could be done with `String.toFloat`.

In the `update` function you will handle both of the `Ok` and `Err` cases for your new message type

```elm
update msg model =
  case msg of
    ...

    NewPlayerLevel (Ok level) ->
      { model | level = Just level, levelError = Nothing }

    NewPlayerLevel (Err err) ->
      { model | level = Nothing, levelError = Just err }
```

which assumes you have a model like this

```elm
type alias Model =
    { ...
    , level : Maybe Int
    , levelError : Maybe String
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Beside the solution provided by @chad-gilbert, you can also provide a function `String -> Msg` that sends different `Msg`s depending on the result. For example:

```
type Msg
    = ...
    | NewPlayerLevel Int
    | IncorrectInput String

newPlayerLevelInput : String -> Msg
newPlayerLevelInput input =
    case String.toInt input of
        Ok int -> NewPlayerLevel int
        Err error -> IncorrectInput error
```

In your `input` function you would use `onInput newPlayerLevelInput` as an attribute.